# react-router v4 alternative for v2 match({routes, location}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {})

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to know if react-router v4 supports match or doesn't. The docs say so, but I keep getting `TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.match) is not a function` or is there an alternative which fulfills all that match () did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4.0 is a complete rewrite. You will need to rethink much of how you do things and there isn't a straightforward upgrade path. For server
>   rendering, check out that specific guide:
>   https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering

That was the answer from timdorr, one of the collaborators of react-router in github.